# Members of object not being returned by PropertyInfo c#

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0, propertyinfo

I'm trying to use PropertyInfo interate through a class and create a datatable from it.  However it returns no values.  I'm a little stumped;

```
public class thetransactions
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string Surname;
    public string PreviousOwner;
    public string NewOwner;
    public string postcode;
    public string[] FileName;
}
```

Then do the legwork with this code;

```
theTransactions[] thetransactions = new theTransactions[10];
thetransactions[0] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<theTransactions>(mydatastring);

PropertyInfo[] properties = thetransactions.GetType().GetElementType().GetProperties();
DataTable sampletable = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = null;

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.ColumnName = pi.Name;
    dc.DataType = pi.PropertyType;
    sampletable.Columns.Add(dc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining *normal* variables in your `thetransactions` class and not properties:

```
public class thetransactions
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string Surname{get;set;}
    public string PreviousOwner{get;set;}
    public string NewOwner{get;set;}
    public string postcode{get;set;}
    public string[] FileName{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException when I change to look at [0], strange because there are objects present.  My only hunch is perhaps some of my properties are null, for example NewOwner has a null value attached.  Although I'm not particularly interested in the values, just want to grab the column names and types.

Comment: I've updated my answer; it should solve your problem now. The first version of my answer contained the wrong hint; sorry for that

Comment: Fantastic!  I presume PropertyInfo calls the get method for each type?

Comment: The `PropertyInfo` just stores all the information of a property, e.g. its name (`FirstName`) and its type (`System.String`). `GetProperties()` uses the Reflection API to compile an array with information about every property of a class / type.